# CPUs not fully used when using Python Ray for parallel processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

first post here, so first of all thanks a lot for this insanely helpful community!

I am running a parallel bioinformatics calculation using Ray with Python 3.6.
I've set it up to run on an AWS EC2 instance with 64 cores on Ubuntu 18. I have to add I am fairly new to Python and especially Ray.

The code is:

```py
    @ray.remote
    def calculate_stuff(sequence): # computationally intensive function calling on external SWIG wrapped C-Code
        fc = external_function(sequence)
        return fc

    ray.init()
    result_ids = []
    
    for i in permutlist: # permutlist is large list containing large strings (300 - 1000 chars)
        result_ids.append(calculate_stuff.remote(i))
    
    allmfe = ray.get(result_ids)
```

This code runs for quite some hours, one loop of calculate_stuff takes ~1s.

I run the script using tmux, when I leave the session and check for CPU usage with `mpstat -P ALL`
the output is:

```
09:37:22     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
09:37:22     all   62.16    0.00    0.26    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.56
09:37:22       0   62.28    0.00    0.26    0.00    0.00    0.05    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.41
09:37:22       1   62.22    0.00    0.25    0.00    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.51
09:37:22       2   62.24    0.00    0.26    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.48
09:37:22       3   62.27    0.00    0.26    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.46
09:37:22       4   62.37    0.00    0.29    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.33
09:37:22       5   62.23    0.00    0.28    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.48
09:37:22       6   62.24    0.00    0.27    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   0.00   37.48
```

This looks the same for all 64 cores.

My question now: Why do I get only 2/3 CPU usage and wasting 1/3 on idling?

Anyone who can help me save time and therefore money more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: this problem will be due to the ubuntu scheduler. user space programs arn't allowed to decide how much they run on the cpu; it is the OS that decides that

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. When I run the same code on my virtual machine using the same Ubuntu distribution I get 100% CPU usage for all 4 available cores. Is this an AWS thing that can be changed somewhere?